# Anyone record this 1000 horn symphony?

Tags: field-recording, art

Some artist had 1000 cars honk their horns in LA today, anyone record it?

[THE LINK](http://www.scpr.org/news/2012/02/16/31270/artist-flair-disruption-sounds-horns-la-traffic/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the KPCC video link, it's great: http://www.scpr.org/news/2012/02/16/31270/artist-flair-disruption-sounds-horns-la-traffic/

And stay tuned For Zefrey's video which we'll have very shortly!

For more information, please email me at hilary@hilarywhite.com, call me at 310-625-1608
or send me a tweet at @hilwhite1

Thanks! Glad you liked it.

Hilary White